# SKAction(named: from:) works in simulator but returns nil on device

Tags: skaction

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyActions_HornLounge", withExtension: "sks")

let a = SKAction(named: "tapMousehole", from: url!, duration: 5)

In the simulator, this works. (edit: works for iOS 11.0, but not 10.3)

On the device, the file is found and the URL is set properly, but returns nil for the action.

Is this some kind of security/read protect issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked on the 11.0 simulator, I installed 11.0 beta 10 on my iPad, SKAction(named: from:) now works on my iPad device.

It seems to me there is a bug in iOS 10.3